# Google bigquery SQL - Separate text and place into different columns using underscore as a separator

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have

```
P2_PCM_C_L112_2011_00_1v  
P2_PCM_C_L212_2012_00_1v  
P2_PCM_C_L119_2011_00_1v  
P2_PCM_C_L6712_2012_00_1v  
P2_PCM_C_L17612_2014_00_1v
```

but I would like to have them all separated and placed into rows, separated by the underscore.
What would the code be for legacy SQL (its for google BigQuery)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple method uses `split()`:

```
select split(col, '_')[safe_ordinal(1)] as part1,
       split(col, '_')[safe_ordinal(2)] as part2,
       split(col, '_')[safe_ordinal(3)] as part3,
       split(col, '_')[safe_ordinal(4)] as part4,
       split(col, '_')[safe_ordinal(5)] as part5,
       split(col, '_')[safe_ordinal(6)] as part6,
       split(col, '_')[safe_ordinal(7)] as part7
from t;
```

Note:  You might find that simply leaving the parts in an array is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(key) from (
  select to_json_string(t) key, offset, part 
  from `project.dataset.table` t,
  unnest(split(text, '_')) part with offset
)
pivot (max(part) for offset in 
  (0 as col1, 1 as col2, 2 as col3, 3 as col4, 4 as col5, 5 as col6, 6 as col7)
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]